# How to generate bar using decoder

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, decoder

Ic74154 decoder generate active low o/p i.e for example if input is binary 5 , 4 becomes low.  I want a circuit which will give output when i/p is binary 5 then o/p is low for 0 to 4.It is possible by using very large no. of FET but it is very costly.

Comment: Subtract 1 and OR the two together, unless the first output is all 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you don't mention the values 6 and 7  (110, 111) you can simplify this problem to a simple AND gate (2^2 AND 2^0). Using a very inexpensive 4011 NAND gate gives the circuit below.

[image]

In view of Michael's comment (the OQ not being clear) the 16 outputs could be converted using three 7404 hex inverters.

[image]

Comment: Similar comment here as on the other answer. I believe that the OP wants to be able to see the input vary even up to 6 or 7 and likely also include all the lower values and get the outputs to respond as a bar graph type display decoder would work.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Thanks for that. I've added a solution that should cover that possibility.